# Owner/Group issue on Mirror server

Tags: linux, nginx, mirror, glusterfs, owner

I am running **Gluster-FS** with a **High-Availability Storage** setup.

Both client and server nodes have **NginX** running to serve same files.

```
main.mysite.com
mirror1.mysite.com
..etc..
```

The problem is that the mirror nodes can't serve files because the owner and group is different.

The owner/group on main server is : `web1:client0`

and in order to make mirror nodes be able to serve files, their owner/group should be :

`www-data:www-data`

But because they're being copied from the main server, the owner/group attribute is same as  `web1:client0`

What's the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You should keep users in sync between the web nodes, in this way you will be able to share data between them without ownership issues.

Since usually web workers are all clones from a single template, you should simply create a script that do an rsync over passwd and group file.

as a side note you can always change the user which is used by apache even on a per site basis, using an apache module like mod_itk.